# Inverse operation for Javascript's Function.toString()

Tags: javascript

For Javascript application I need to be able to let the user save the state of an object. This involves saving a set of custom functions that were previously created dynamically or through a GUI, and loading these stored functions later. Essentially I need to serialize and unserialize functions.

Right now I achieve the serialize part by using the Function object's .toString() method:

```
func.toString().replace('"', '\"').replace(/(\r)/g, ' ').replace(/(\n)/g, ' ').replace(/(\t)/g, ' ')
```

This gives me "serialized" functions like this beauty (note that the function is unnamed):

```
"function (someParameter) {this.someFunctionName(return 'something';}"
```

Unserializing this is where I struggle. My current best solution for unserializing the functions is this:

```
var func = eval( 't =' +  so.actions[i].func);
```

Note how I prepend the serialized function with `t =` before calling `eval()` on it. I don't like doing this because it creates a global variable but I cannot find a way around it. When not prepending this, I receive a "SyntaxError: Unexpected token (". When prepending `var t =`, eval() does not return the function but `undefined`.

Are there alternative ways to "unserialize" an unnamed function?

PS: I am aware of the security implications of using eval() on user input. For the foreseeable future I am the only user of this software, so this is currently a non-issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the Function constructor to avoid creating a global variable:

```
var func = Function("return " + so.actions[i].func)();
```

This is equivalent to:

```
var func = eval("(function () { return " + so.actions[i].func + " })()");
```

One thing to be wary of is the surrounding closure which you won't be able to capture, so variables inside the function will "change" when you serialize and de-serialize.

**edit**

I'm not thinking, you can of course just do:

```
var func = eval("(" + so.actions[i].func + ")");
```

Comment: The closure is taken care of. These functions are only ever executed by using `Function.call(theContextTheFunctionIsExecutedIn)`. That aside your suggestion to surround the serialized function with brackets works - do you know why?

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope), adding the parens changes it from a function *declaration* to a function *expression*. (It's part of an expression in the parens.) Since it is an expression, it'll return a value, that you can assign to `func`. This also might depend on the scope that the eval is currently in.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
eval('var func = ' + so.actions[i].func);
```