# Convert string from regexp match into object

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
var str = 'jfkdjffddf{aaa:12,bbb:25}kfdjf';
```

And I want to fetch the object from it:

```
var objStr = str.match('/{(.*?)}/')[1]; // aaa:12,bbb:25
```

Now I want to use this fetched string as an object:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{' + objStr + '}');
```

Do some operations on it, convert to string back again and replace in the initial text.

The problem is I get `unexpected token a` on 1 line in my script, the problem is thus probably `JSON.parse`.

What's the problem, and how can I solve this?

Comment: It's not valid JSON. In JSON, the property names have to be enclosed in quotation marks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inverse operation for Javascript's Function.toString()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781861/inverse-operation-for-javascripts-function-tostring)

Comment: @soren Are you suggesting he use `eval()` to turn this into a JavaScript object?

Comment: Now I get `unexpected token :`, even though the json seems to be valid - `{"aaa":"12","bbb":"25"}`

Comment: try with `objStr.replace(/([^:,]*?):([0-9]+)/g,"\"$1\":\"$2\"")`

Comment: @KarolHernik I typed `JSON.parse('{"aaa":"12","bbb":"25"}')` into console, and it worked fine. Are you sure that's what you are feeding to `JSON.parse`?

Comment: @crush - "Ahh i can use rexexp for this problem, and now you have two problems" -- the regexp you provided is creating invaild syntax and converts the numbers into strings, and for more complex document with nested structures & arrays it may be worse -- while `eval` has security issues for untrusted data, then that _may_ be the best solution for this problem, since the data is not in JSON format

Comment: What do you think about [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a204no36/)? Does it solve your problem?